# How to extract form element values in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of form elements that I want to loop over to get the values of, so if someone typed their name in the input i want their name, if they selected an option from a select box I want the not the numerical value but the string. All these values needs to be outputted as one string.

This is the loop i've created, I however have no idea how to go about this problem..

every form element has a name starting with credit_

if someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated..

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('[name*=credit_]').each(function( index ){

});
```

my html is quite simple.

```
<div class="comp-row">
     <!-- a select -->
     <!-- an input -->
</div>
```

This is part of the form, there are many other form fields but im only concerned with the ones within "comp-row" which Im manipulating a lot.

I ended up using:

```
$('.comp-row [name*="credit_"]:not([type=hidden])')
.each(function(index,elem)
{
    console.log($(this).text() != '' ? $(this).find('option:selected').text().trim() : $(this).val());
});
}
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: I agree with @qwertynl, it would be useful to see this. Could you maybe set up a jsFiddle or similar as a starting point?

Comment: you only set the name for the `select` and the `input` right? name property is invalid for `option` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre looking for the `$('select[name*="credit_"]>option:selected')` selector.

To read the text value for your , issue `.text()`

Combine this with `if($('input[name*="credit_"]').text() != '')` evaluation, combined something like this:

```
var theName = $('input[name*="credit_"]').text() != '' 
   ? $('select[name*="credit_"]>option:selected').text() 
   : $('input[name*="credit_"]').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on format you want you can use `serialize()` or `serializeArray()`.

For example to obtain for whole form:

```
var data=$('#myForm').serialize()
```

For specific group of elements:

```
$('[name*=credit_]').serializeArray()
```

[serialize() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

[serializeArray() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Comment: ah no this is part of a form, there are many other form fields within the form but im concerned with only a section.

Comment: `.serialize` will get the value of a select option, he wants the text of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = '';
$(this).parent().parent().find('[name*=credit_]').each(function( index ){
    result += $(this).is("select") ? $(this).text() : $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all elements that match your criteria (`name*=credit_`). Check its type and put the value inside a variable.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="credit_a" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="credit_b" value="2" />
    <input type="text" name="credit_c" value="3" />
    <select name="credit_d">
        <option value="kk">kk</option>
        <option value="jj" selected>jjjjj</option>
    </select>
    <input name="credit_e type="checkbox" checked value="imchecked" />
</form>

<form>
    <input type="text" name="credit_a" value="55" />
    <input type="text" name="credit_b" value="66" />
    <input type="text" name="credit_c" value="77" />
    <input type="text" name="credit_d" value="88" />
</form>

<p id="result"> </p>
```

**javascript**

```
$(function() {
    var values = '';

    $('form [name*=credit_]').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if($this[0].tagName == 'TEXTAREA') {
            values += ' ' + $this.text();   
        } 
        else if ($this[0].tagName == 'SELECT') {
            values += ' ' + $this.find(':selected').text();
        }
        else {
            values += ' ' + $this.val();
        }   
    });

    $('#result').html(values);    
});
```

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/5tgzr/2/